# Automatic Send Update eMail

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to start manege orders from suppliers.
I build a orders pages, that in one side- mine, i can place a new order, and
the 2nd side, the supplier, can see the orders, and update the status of every item.

Now, what i need is to automatic send mail to the supplier when sending the order, And the same for when each item is being ready for shipment.

What can be a good way to do it[no PHP if possible]? is it with node.js? cause when i checked Formspree for example, it was good only for sending to one mail address (like contact-us form).

Thank you

Comment: so, basically what you're asking is, how to send emails with node.js?

Comment: Have a look at [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/)

Answer (score 0):

To send an email from node.js, you can use [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).

Example (copied from main website):

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.example.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
    auth: {
        user: 'username@example.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});

// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
}
console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```